# Sending AD Attributes as AD FS claims to Shibboleth SP Attributes

Tags: adfs, shibboleth

I have an AD FS claims provider set up and a Shibboleth SP successfully authenticating against it.

I am attempting to have the Active Directory attributes sent to the SP.

I followed this article to attempt to send the claims:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317734(v=ws.10).aspx

The relevant section is `Step 2: Configure AD FS 2.0 as the Identity Provider and Shibboleth as the Relying Party` --> `Configure AD FS 2.0` --> `Edit Claim Rules for Relying Party Trust` --> `To configure eduPerson claims for sending to a relying party trust`:

In Step 16, it states that I should paste or type the following (and has it in 2 code blocks):

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group", Value == "Domain Users"]
```

and

```
=> issue(Type = "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.9", Value = "member@contoso.com", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/attributename"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri");
```

I believe that it was meant to be a single statement (please correct me if I'm wrong) so my entry is as follows:

[image]

I am testing with the givenName, so I added the following:
[image]

On the Shibboleth SP machine, I edited the `attribute-map.xml` by adding the following and then I restarted the Shibboleth service:

```
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:GivenName" id="GivenName"/>
```

When I browsed to the website and re-authenticated with AD FS, I am not seeing the givenName showing.  I have an index file that outputs all of the headers and their values.

---

**Edit: Solution to my issue**

---

I got the UPN to send as the epPN.  The above rules (the rules in the article) worked, but I had to edit the `attribute-policy.xml` on the Shibboleth SP to disable the scoping rules, since I didn't have that part set up properly.

I commented out the following lines in the `attribute-policy.xml`

```
afp:AttributeRule attributeID="eppn">
    <afp:PermitValueRuleReference ref="ScopingRules"/>
</afp:AttributeRule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the claims rule (displayed in two lines) is one 'statement'. It ends with the ';'. I.e. you add both lines to the same custom rule.

For each issued (send) Claim (Attribute) with an object identifier uri, you need to add a custom rule (below the AD search rule). That is, if you want the "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri". If you just want the oid uri, then defining the clam in "Claim Descriptions" is enough.

Normally I use a slight variation on the program. I write the search rule with the UI, but then I copy the rule (from "View Rule Language") to a custom rule. In the copied custom rule I change "issue" to "add". And then I delete the original search rule. This avoids sending both the URL and URN claims to Shib.